# SQL create new column based on value of one occurrence in another column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to fill out a column based on the value of one occurrence in another column.

To illustrate, this is a snippet of a Google Analytics dataset:

```
UID         event_name       params.key             params.value.string_value  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc         first_open       firebase_event_origin  auto  
abc         user_engagement  firebase_screen        Login Screen  
abc         view_item        item_id                Grade 2
xyz         user_engagement  firebase_screen        Profile Screen    
xyz         view_item        item_id                Grade 11
```

I want to add a Grade column that looks like this:

```
UID         event_name       params.key             params.value.string_value    Grade
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc         first_open       firebase_event_origin  auto                         Grade 2  
abc         user_engagement  firebase_screen        Login Screen                 Grade 2  
abc         view_item        item_id                Grade 2                      Grade 2  
xyz         user_engagement  firebase_screen        Profile Screen               Grade 11  
xyz         view_item        item_id                Grade 11                     Grade 11
```

I've tried

```
SELECT UID, params.value.string_value AS Grade 
FROM `Google_Analytics` 
WHERE params.key="item_id"
```

and then joined the resulting dataset with the `Google_Analytics` dataset. But I was wondering if there's a way to do this in the original dataset `Google_Analytics` without having to create a new dataset --> join with the original dataset.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select ga.*,
       max(case when params.key = 'item_id' then params.value.string_value end) over (partition by uid) as grade
from `Google_Analytics` ga;
```

I'm not sure if you also want `view_item` in the condition as well.

Comment: This is so helpful! Thank you so much :)